# Django Template For Loop Removing <img> Self-Closing

Tags: django, django-templates, xhtml

Django's for loop seems to be removing all of my `<img>` tag's self-closing...ness (`/>`). In the Template, I have this code:

```
{% for item in item_list %}
<li>
    <a class="left" href="{{ item.url }}">{{ item.name }}</a>
    <a class="right" href="{{ item.url }}">
        <img src="{{ item.icon.url }}" alt="{{ item.name }} Logo." />
    </a>
</li>
{% endfor %}
```

It outputs this:

```
<li>
    <a class="left" href="/some-url/">This is an item</a>
    <a class="right" href="/some-url/">
        <img src="/media/img/some-item.jpg" alt="This is an item Logo.">
    </a>
</li>
```

As you can see, the `<img>` tag is no longer closed, and thus the page doesn't validate. This isn't a huge issue since it'll still *render* properly in all browsers, but I'd like to know how to solve it. I've tried wrapping the whole for loop in `{% autoescape off %}...{% endautoescape %}` but that didn't change anything. All other self-closed `<img>` tags in the document **outside** the for loop still properly close.

Comment: First of all, output does not match input - "This is an item Logo." - You do not have full-stop in the template. Secondly, I could not reproduce this kind of behaviour :(

Comment: I modified the code to ambiguate the purpose, I missed that typo, but the purpose is still the same. Also, which version of Django are you using? I'm using 1.2b1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django's template engine is not capable of making this change. Are you sure this is the code you see when you do View Source?

Comment: Yes, also on the W3C's validator (this is where I initially noticed it).

Comment: Oh wow, I'm quite a moron. I just realized that it was a child template overwriting the code in the base template. So this would be correct as Django's template engine is indeed not capable of making this change.